# Handle versionned user-specific configurations in forks

Tags: git

I wrote a bunch of VM setup scripts for myself, and then shared them with my team so that they can have a similar setup. Some adjustments need to be made by other team members depending on the projects they work on.

The way I set this up is with a main git repository that contains the scripts and a dummy configuration file. I have a fork of this repo where I keep my custom config.

**What is a practical way (avoid git conflicts and risks of pushing the custom config to the main repo) of handling updates to the scripts ?**

Should I always work directly on the main repo, then manually merge the changes in my fork ? Should I do a PR from my fork and have a way to filter out the configuration ? Something else ?

Comment: Can you use environment variables? That's simplest option. Alternatives include only committing a template file and using a script to generate the "real" script.

Comment: That would be quite impractical : user-specific differences include the list of internal repositories to clone, it's not just flags or options like that.

Comment: Actually, I guess those could be shared as "profiles" (in the template file that you mention for example) that you choose from as you install the repo